# Complexity Lower Bounds for 3D Sparse Gaussian Elimination

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, lower-bounds, linear-algebra

I'm interested in lower bounds on the complexity in the real-RAM model of solving systems of linear equations which have the sparsity pattern of a three-dimensional cubic mesh. Specifically, consider a matrix $A$ whose rows and columns are indexed by points in $\{1,\ldots,\sqrt[3]{N}\}^3$ with a nonzero entry in row $(i_1,i_2,i_3)$ and column $(j_1,j_2,j_3)$ only if $|i_1 - j_1| + |i_2 - j_2| + |i_3 - j_3| \le 1$. The problem is:

> Given the $\mathcal{O}(N)$ nonzero entries comprising $A$ and $m$ right-hand sides $b_1,\ldots,b_m$, compute $x_1 = A^{-1}b_1,\ldots,x_n = A^{-1}b_n$.

The prototypical example of this is the discrete Poisson equation in 3D or more generally a (generalized) Laplacian matrix on the three-dimensional mesh graph. There are results which show that if one additionally assumes $A$ is diagonally dominant, then approximate solutions $\tilde{x}_1,\ldots,\tilde{x}_n$ can be computed in $\tilde{\mathcal{O}}(mN)$ time. I'm interested in the case where there is no diagonal dominance assumption, and am in particular curious about the case where $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ are required to be computed exactly.

My understanding is the lower bound of [Lipton, Rose, and Tarjan](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0716027?casa_token=bqyUvtRsYO0AAAAA:N0KyzxwLxYevKklE2YE1Y7CjwOkP2eeQk6xIhknBpCvuMJhMLnPkRBs6E46wn9Og6W3EqCcNG6Y) extends to the 3D case and thus solving such systems *by Gaussian elimination* requires $\mathcal{O}(N^2 + mN^{4/3})$ arithmetic operations, where $\mathcal{O}(N^2)$ are required to compute the factorization and $\mathcal{O}(N^{4/3})$ operations are required per right-hand side to do back- and forward-substitution. I believe this can be improved to $\mathcal{O}(N^{2\omega/3} + mN^{4/3})$ by using fast matrix multiplication algorithms, where $\omega \ge 2$ is the exponent of matrix multiplication. It seems that, in some sense, Gaussian elimination with a good elimination ordering is the "natural" algorithm for this problem. However, I am not aware of any truly general lower bounds for this problem. I know algebraic complexity bounds are hard to prove, but are such results known?

Comment: Would you consider randomized results?

Comment: @user3483902 Yes certainly. I would be surprised if randomization helped if one wants the solution computed exactly, but I would be happy to be proven wrong. I also limited the scope of my question to results for exact computation of $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ to keep the question direct, but I would certainly also be interested in lower bounds for approximate solution as well.